# Compiling Java with multiple classes with javac

Tags: java

Until now I always used an IDE to write my java apps. Now for different reasons, mainly also to understand more about the language and the things the IDE is just making for you, I switched to vim and have now the following problem:

I wrote two classes:

```
package seedInformatik.LinearList;

import seedInformatik.LinearList.*;

// A linear list. Contains LinearListElement<T>
public class LinearList<T> {
```

and

```
package seedInformatik.LinearList; 

public class ListElement<T> {
```

Now I want to compile LinearList and get the following:

```
➜  LinearList javac LinearList.java
LinearList.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    private ListElement<T> first; // head of list
            ^
```

Both classes are in the same dir. What do I miss?

Many Thanks
Robin

Comment: what is the exact javac command you are using?

Comment: I'd suggest looking into a build tool like Gradle, but otherwise, you can compile all Java files in one directory with `javac *.java`.

Comment: thanks for the comments the javac *.java does the job as marked below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
javac *.java // compliles all java files in the dir

java MyClass // runs the particular file
```

If your files are under some package you need to specify the package like this:

```
javac com.mypackage/.*java

java com.mypackage.MyClass
```

I would also recommend using a build tool like maven: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_make_my_first_Maven_project