# Java Error: bad source file: file does not contain class

Tags: java

The directory of `QueryFeatureExtract.java` is like

```
gen-java/
└── query_feature
    └── QueryFeatureExtract.java
```

and the java file `ThriftClient.java` which use `QueryFeatureExtract` is in the same folder with `gen-java`, I want to compile `Client.java` with

```
javac -classpath libthrift-0.9.1.jar:slf4j.jar -sourcepath gen-java/query_feature/ ThriftClient.java
```

Then the error shows

```
ThriftClient.java:16: error: cannot access QueryFeatureExtract
            QueryFeatureExtract.Client client = new QueryFeatureExtract.Client(protocol);
            ^
  bad source file: gen-java/query_feature/QueryFeatureExtract.java
    file does not contain class QueryFeatureExtract
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
1 error
```

Comment: What is the package declaration of QueryFeatureExtract ? Shouldn't you use -sourcepath gen-java/ instead of gen-java/query_feature/ ?

Comment: @Raphaël Use this, it will show error package QueryFeatureExtract does not exist.. the package declaration of QueryFeatureExtract is "package query_feature;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your files are like this:

```
./
└── ThriftClient.java
└── gen-java/
|   └── query_feature/
|       └── QueryFeatureExtract.java
└── libthrift-0.9.1.jar
└── slf4j.jar
```

And `QueryFeatureExtract` begins with the following package declaration:

```
package query_feature;
```

You should use the following command to compile `ThriftClient.java`:

```
javac -classpath .:libthrift-0.9.1.jar:slf4j.jar:gen-java ThriftClient.java
```

You can specify folders with `-classpath`, you don't need to use `-sourcepath`. Don't forget to add `.` to your class path if you have other java files in the current folder. To avoid errors since you have a source path containing an other source path, I would recommand moving `ThriftClient.java` into a folder named `src`.

If it does not work, check that `ThriftClient` is importing `QueryFeatureExtract` with the correct import:

```
import query_feature.QueryFeatureExtract;
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! BUT the another error "Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again". Is this related to Class QueryFeatureExtract?

Comment: JNI means that your Java code is calling a C or C++ library. The library may have crashed or you may have path problems when launching your app. Since I don't now which file is using JNI, I can't tell you if it is related to QueryFeatureExtract.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823499/compiling-java-with-multiple-classes-with-javac), You are just compiling ThriftClient, try this:

```
javac -classpath libthrift-0.9.1.jar:slf4j.jar -sourcepath gen-java/query_feature/ *.java
```

Comment: @danche notice the star (*.java) at the end

Comment: @danche I thought your problem was QueryFeatureExtract.java? Dont you want to compile this class too?

Comment: Yes, But it is same after compile it or not...when I put the ThriftClient.java under gen-java/query_feature, it will cause package QueryFeatureExtract does not exist error.. very confused...

Comment: @danche my bad i thought Thrift and Query classes is in same package